# how to split the csv columns into multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data has below format

```
Version ID   Col1_ErrorCode  Col2_ErrorCode   Col3_ErrorCode  Col1_CID   Col2_CID    Col3_CID
1.0.0   555  1111            2222             3333            AAA       BBB          CCC
```

I would like to have error code and CID into different rows like below.

```
Version  ID    Error    CID
1.0.0    555   1111     AAA
1.0.0    555   2222     BBB
1.0.0    555   3333     CCC
```

Can anyone please help me how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `set_index` then `stack`

```
s = df.set_index(['Version','ID'])
s.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple))
out = s.stack(level=0).reset_index()
Out[315]: 
  Version   ID level_2  CID  ErrorCode
0   1.0.0  555    Col1  AAA       1111
1   1.0.0  555    Col2  BBB       2222
2   1.0.0  555    Col3  CCC       3333
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `wide_to_long`, but we need to fix your column names that way the stubs, 'CID' and 'ErrorCode', come before the underscore.

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(x[::-1]) for x in df.columns.str.split('_')]

df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['ErrorCode', 'CID'],
                      i=['Version', 'ID'], j='to_drop', suffix='.*', sep='_')
        .reset_index()
        .drop(columns='to_drop'))
```

---

```
print(df)
  Version   ID  ErrorCode  CID
0   1.0.0  555       1111  AAA
1   1.0.0  555       2222  BBB
2   1.0.0  555       3333  CCC
```